# How can you shorten the multiple if-else construct?

Tags: java, if-statement

my program recognizes the entered text as a command, now everything looks like this:

```
        out.print("Welcome " + nameProperty + " to the program!\n" +
                "Input your command: ");
        setChooseAction(scanner.nextLine());

        new Logger().commandLoggerWriter(getChooseAction());
        if (chooseAction.contains("string")) {
            out.println("Available methods for string:\n " +
                    "Substring\n " +
                    "Append\n" +
                    " toLowerCase" +
                    "\n toUpperCase" +
                    "\n Replace");
            out.print("Enter method: ");
            setChooseAction(scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase());
            new Logger().LogSubMethod(getChooseAction());
            if (chooseAction.contains("substring")) {
                new StringProcessing().substringString();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("contains")) {

            }

            if (chooseAction.contains("append")) {
                new StringProcessing().appendString();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("tolowercase")) {
                new StringProcessing().toLowerCaseString();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("touppercase")) {
                new StringProcessing().toUpperCaseString();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("replace")) {
                new StringProcessing().replaceString();
            }
        }
        if (chooseAction.contains("calc")) {
            out.println("Available methods for calculator:\n " +
                    "Sum\n" +
                    "minus\n" +
                    "multiplication\n" +
                    "division\n" +
                    "interest\n" +
                    "sqrt\n" +
                    "cbrt\n" +
                    "pow\n" +
                    "sin\n" +
                    "cos\n" +
                    "dis[discernment]\n" +
                    "tan\n" +
                    "average\n" +
                    "asin\n" +
                    "acos\n" +
                    "atan\n" +
                    "log\n" +
                    "log10\n" +
                    "sinh\n" +
                    "cosh\n" +
                    "tanh\n"
            );
            setChooseAction(scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase());
            new Logger().LogSubMethod(getChooseAction());
            if (chooseAction.contains("sum")) {
                new Calculator().sumComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("minus")) {
                new Calculator().minusComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("multiplication")) {
                new Calculator().multiplicationComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("division")) {
                new Calculator().divisionComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("interest")) {
                new Calculator().interestComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("sqrt")) {
                new Calculator().sqrtComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("cbrt")) {
                new Calculator().cbrtComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("pow")) {
                new Calculator().powComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("sin")) {
                new Calculator().sinComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("cos")) {
                new Calculator().cosComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("tan")) {
                new Calculator().tanComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("dis")) {
                new Calculator().disc();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("average")) {
                new Calculator().averageComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("asin")) {
                new Calculator().asinComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("acos")) {
                new Calculator().acosComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("atan")) {
                new Calculator().acosComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("log")) {
                new Calculator().logComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("log10")) {
                new Calculator().log10Complete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("sinh")) {
                new Calculator().sinhComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("cosh")) {
                new Calculator().coshComplete();
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("tanh")) {
                new Calculator().tanhComplete();
            }

        }
        if (chooseAction.contains("info")) {
            out.println("Available methods for info:\n " +
                    "System");
            setChooseAction(scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase());
            new Logger().LogSubMethod(getChooseAction());
            if (chooseAction.contains("system")) {
                new SystemInfo().getSystemInfo();
            }
        }
        if (chooseAction.contains("time")) {
            Date date = new Date();
            out.println("Current time: " + date);
            out.println("--------------------------------");
            Menu();
        }
        if (chooseAction.contains("ip")) {
            out.println("Your ip: " + new GetIp().getIp());
        }
        if (chooseAction.contains("check")) {
            new CheckFilesAndDirectory().allCheck();
            out.println("Check complete.");
            new MainMenu().Menu();

        }
        if (chooseAction.contains("log")) {
            out.println("Available methods for log:\n " +
                    "Show\n" +
                    "Clear");
            setChooseAction(scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase());
            new Logger().LogSubMethod(getChooseAction());
            if (chooseAction.contains("show")) {
                out.println("1 - All logs   2 - Commands log  3 - Session logs");
                setEnterChooseNumber(scanner.nextInt());
                int chooseNumber = getEnterChooseNumber();
                if (chooseNumber == 1) {
                    try {
                        new LogReader().allLogReader();
                        mm.Menu();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                } else if (chooseNumber == 2) {
                    try {
                        new LogReader().logCommandReader();
                        mm.Menu();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                } else if (chooseNumber == 3) {
                    try {
                        new LogReader().logSessionReader();
                        mm.Menu();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("exit")) {
                out.println("Bye bye!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
```

how can i get rid of this huge if-els construct?

I tried to put everything into separate methods in order to comply with the principle of uniqueness, but it didn’t work out, since checking if else is still needed everywhere. thanks for the help

Comment: "how can i get rid of this huge if-els construct?" you can't really, as you are using `contains` to check. If you used `equals`, you could change to a `switch` or use a `Map`.

Comment: Why do you want? If it isn't broken, don't fix it as we say.. I actually seen much worse than this. When you have lots of alternatives, you'll have lots of if/else or switch. switch doesn't save lots of code anyway, I don't see it used that much. You can save code where you test `chooseNumber`, the `try...catch` can be before the if, as the catch raises the same type of error for all cases

Comment: One possibility would be to extract the tokens beforehand, store them in some configuration-object and feed this configuration-object into a [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Comment: `contains()` is probably a bad choice. It will match anything that contains the string, like `contains("substring")` will return true for input `"abcd1234substringikdjfnv@"`.

Comment: @Kaddath a cascase of `if-else`, or a large `switch` increases friction and coupling. A more dynamic approach reduces friction and coupling.

Comment: @Turing85 yes but it doesn't seem to be the low hanging fruit in this code, I would be more worried about the number of calls to `contains`, your suggestion to extract tokens beforehand is very valid in this perspective. I also think the question would be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as the code works

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice, I was just told that this is a noodle code, and it somehow needs to be remade by removing if els.

Comment: @InnerException, you're using _contains_.  Will _chooseAction_ be just one word, or a sentence?

Comment: You could indeed map the command strings to the commands using a `Map`: `Map<String, Consumer<StringProcessing>> map = Map.of("append", StringProcessing::appendString, "tolowercase", StringProcessing::toLowerCaseString, ...)`

Comment: @Reilas its just one word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few approaches.

Is the *chooseAction* just one word, or multiple?

For one word, you can use a switch statement.
This will, at least, reduce the amount of space the code occupies.

As a note, you can use the *[String#equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))* or *[String#equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))* methods for comparison.
Additionally, there is *[String#startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))*, and *[String#endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))*.

Since I don't have your entire code, here is an example.

A note here, you have an *acosComplete* method call for *atan*, looks like a typo.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String chooseAction = scanner.nextLine();
switch (chooseAction) {
    case "sum" -> new Calculator().sumComplete();
    case "minus" -> new Calculator().minusComplete();
    case "multiplication" -> new Calculator().multiplicationComplete();
    case "division" -> new Calculator().divisionComplete();
    case "interest" -> new Calculator().interestComplete();
    case "sqrt" -> new Calculator().sqrtComplete();
    case "cbrt" -> new Calculator().cbrtComplete();
    case "pow" -> new Calculator().powComplete();
    case "sin" -> new Calculator().sinComplete();
    case "cos" -> new Calculator().cosComplete();
    case "tan" -> new Calculator().tanComplete();
    case "dis" -> new Calculator().disc();
    case "average" -> new Calculator().averageComplete();
    case "asin" -> new Calculator().asinComplete();
    case "acos", "atan" -> new Calculator().acosComplete();
    case "log" -> new Calculator().logComplete();
    case "log10" -> new Calculator().log10Complete();
    case "sinh" -> new Calculator().sinhComplete();
    case "cosh" -> new Calculator().coshComplete();
    case "tanh" -> new Calculator().tanhComplete();
}
```

After reviewing your code further, I believe the *chooseAction* string most likely contains more than one word.

So, this approach is more involved.

The concept here is to use a *[regular expression pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*—also referred to as *regex*.
By utilizing a *regex pattern*, we can, essentially, simulate the *String#contains* method.

If you're not familiar, *regex* is not specific to *Java*, many languages implement it.
It's commonly used in *Unix*.
It is not a language, per se, just a syntax.  It's used to match *string* values.

*Wikipedia* offers an excellent overview.
There are also numerous books, I recommend anything by *O'Reilly Media*.
My personal favorite of theirs is, *[Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-regular-expressions/0596528124/)*.

*Java* offers the *[java.util.regex](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)* framework, which includes the *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* and *[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)* classes.

Here is a full re-factor.
Ironically, I used a *regex* to format the code.

*Regex* can be a confusing topic, so let me know if you have any questions.
If you plan to scale the program, by adding more values, this approach can prove helpful.

As a final note, I fixed the *acosComplete* method call for *atan*.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String chooseAction = scanner.nextLine();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("string|calc|info|system|time|ip|check|log");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(chooseAction);
if (matcher.find()) {
    switch (matcher.group()) {
        case "string" -> {
            pattern = Pattern.compile("substring|contains|append|tolowercase|touppercase|replace");
            matcher = pattern.matcher(chooseAction);
            switch (matcher.group()) {
                case "substring" -> new StringProcessing().substringString();
                case "contains" -> {}
                case "append" -> new StringProcessing().appendString();
                case "tolowercase" -> new StringProcessing().toLowerCaseString();
                case "touppercase" -> new StringProcessing().toUpperCaseString();
                case "replace" -> new StringProcessing().replaceString();
            }
        }
        case "calc" -> {
            pattern = Pattern.compile("sum|minus|multiplication|division|interest|sqrt|cbrt|pow|sin|cos|tan|dis|average|asin|acos|atan|log|log10|sinh|cosh|tanh");
            matcher = pattern.matcher(chooseAction);
            switch (matcher.group()) {
                case "sum" -> new Calculator().sumComplete();
                case "minus" -> new Calculator().minusComplete();
                case "multiplication" -> new Calculator().multiplicationComplete();
                case "division" -> new Calculator().divisionComplete();
                case "interest" -> new Calculator().interestComplete();
                case "sqrt" -> new Calculator().sqrtComplete();
                case "cbrt" -> new Calculator().cbrtComplete();
                case "pow" -> new Calculator().powComplete();
                case "sin" -> new Calculator().sinComplete();
                case "cos" -> new Calculator().cosComplete();
                case "tan" -> new Calculator().tanComplete();
                case "dis" -> new Calculator().disc();
                case "average" -> new Calculator().averageComplete();
                case "asin" -> new Calculator().asinComplete();
                case "acos" -> new Calculator().acosComplete();
                case "atan" -> new Calculator().atanComplete();
                case "log" -> new Calculator().logComplete();
                case "log10" -> new Calculator().log10Complete();
                case "sinh" -> new Calculator().sinhComplete();
                case "cosh" -> new Calculator().coshComplete();
                case "tanh" -> new Calculator().tanhComplete();
            }
        }
        case "info" -> {
            out.println("Available methods for info:\n " +
                "System");
            setChooseAction(scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase());
            new Logger().LogSubMethod(getChooseAction());
            if (chooseAction.contains("system")) {
                new SystemInfo().getSystemInfo();
            }
        }
        case "system" -> {}
        case "time" -> {
            Date date = new Date();
            out.println("Current time: " + date);
            out.println("--------------------------------");
            Menu();
        }
        case "ip" -> out.println("Your ip: " + new GetIp().getIp());
        case "check" -> {
            new CheckFilesAndDirectory().allCheck();
            out.println("Check complete.");
            new MainMenu().Menu();
        }
        case "log" -> {
            out.println("Available methods for log:\n " +
                "Show\n" +
                "Clear");
            setChooseAction(scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase());
            new Logger().LogSubMethod(getChooseAction());
            if (chooseAction.contains("show")) {
                out.println("1 - All logs   2 - Commands log  3 - Session logs");
                setEnterChooseNumber(scanner.nextInt());
                int chooseNumber = getEnterChooseNumber();
                if (chooseNumber == 1) {
                    try {
                        new LogReader().allLogReader();
                        mm.Menu();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                } else if (chooseNumber == 2) {
                    try {
                        new LogReader().logCommandReader();
                        mm.Menu();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                } else if (chooseNumber == 3) {
                    try {
                        new LogReader().logSessionReader();
                        mm.Menu();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }
            }
            if (chooseAction.contains("exit")) {
                out.println("Bye bye!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm already learning regular expressions. Since I'm new to Java, I haven't been able to come up with such a thing yet.
There will be many more commands, and I think cases with switches are a great solution. Tell me, if there are 200+ commands in such a program, would it be an effective solution to do it all through regular expressions?

Comment: It depends on the exact requirement.  _Regex_ is specific to matching and, optionally, capturing values within a _string_. If the _String_ class doesn't offer a solution, then yes, that's the typical solution.  If you're matching a single word, then _String_ should suffice.

Comment: If I were doing this I would use `Set<String>` to hold the commands.   They are easy to update and you can use`Set.contains()` to verify existence.  Because `sets` are hashed it is not a linear search.  But nothing wrong with your original approach or using regexes.  Just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @WJS, I was under the presumption they wanted to just reduce the _else-if_ checks.  That's why I didn't progress much.  They have nested values, so maybe, _Map_ of _Set_?

Comment: @Reilas You're correct.  Just thought I would throw that in there as an alternative to substring searches and regexes.  There a lots of ways this could go.   But without knowing more details, all is just a guess.  But I would find typing in `keywords` cumbersome.  I would probably write a calculator using RPN entry.

Comment: @WJS, great, maybe update your answer.  Again, I was focusing on the _else-if_ reduction, here.  I didn't plan on interpreting that part of their code.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a Map with a lambda (here a consumer.  You would need to decide which best fits your design as this is just a bare minimum example.  All this does is take in a String and calls the operation if present.  In this case, the operation is to print a string.

```
public class Demo {
    
     Map<String, Consumer<Object>> operations =
        new LinkedHashMap<>(Map.of(
           "div", a -> new Calculator().division(),
           "add", a -> new Calculator().addition(), 
           "mul", a -> new Calculator().multiply(),
           "sub", a -> new Calculator().subtract(),
           "quit", a -> new Calculator().quit()));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("The following operations are availble");
        for (String op : operations.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(op);
        }
        while (true) {
            String op = s.next();
            if (operations.containsKey(op)) {
                operations.get(op).accept(null);
            } else {
              System.out.println(op + " not found");
            } 
        }
    }
}

class Calculator {
    public void division() {
        System.out.println("Division");
    }

    public void addition() {
        System.out.println("Addition");
    }

    public void subtract() {
        System.out.println("subtraction");
    }

    public void multiply() {
        System.out.println("Multiplication");
    }

    public void quit() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Once again, you will have to decide how best to handle this if arguments are involved.  You may even need to write your own functional interface.